# Having trouble accessing value from API response using PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP.

I am trying to echo information from an API which has a response such as:

```
{"id":1111, "library":[{"id":222,"name":"Test"},{"id":444, "name":"Test4"}], "advertiser":{"id":333,"name":"Test2"}}
```

I store this in $api_response_array.

To get the "id" value (1111), I use:

```
$api_response_array('id');
```

To get the library ID value, I use:

```
foreach($api_response_array['library'] as $key=>$value {
    echo $value['id'];
}
```

However, I'm not sure the correct syntax to grab the id value from the advertiser part of the response. I noticed it's wrapped in curly brackets instead of square brackets which tells me it's not an array. But when I try to reference it as an object, I get an error:

```
Code: $api_response_array['advertiser']->id
Error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

Can someone help me with the correct syntax to access this value? Thanks!

Comment: Did you `json_decode` with a true second parameter? Maybe try `$api_response_array['advertiser']['id']`.

Comment: Yes sorry, the json response is stored in $api_response_json and then I used json_decode($api_response_json, true) and stored this information in $api_response_array.

The syntax you provided works great! I am able to get the id value. Didn't realize it was so simple as slapping two square bracket values. Thanks for your help! Feel free to submit this as an answer I can accept.

Comment: The second param being true decodes the entire JSON string into arrays only, not bothering to convert JSON objects into basic PHP stdClass objects. So that means you simply access they as you would any other PHP array.

Answer (score 1):

If you **Dump** your array, then you will see that "library" and "advertiser" are not same.

Here is how your array is:

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1111)
  ["library"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(222)
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Test"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(444)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Test4"
    }
  }
  ["advertiser"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(333)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
  }
}
```

To make it work, try something like:

```
$response = '{"id":1111, "library":[{"id":222,"name":"Test"},{"id":444, "name":"Test4"}], "advertiser":{"id":333,"name":"Test2"}}';
$array = json_decode($response, 1);

// Dump all to see what you have and how to process it like:
var_dump($array);


// Then you can get each value like:

echo $array['id'];
echo $array['library'][0]['id'];
echo $array['library'][0]['name'];
echo $array['library'][1]['id'];
echo $array['library'][1]['name'];

echo $array['advertiser']['id'];
echo $array['advertiser']['name'];
```